# Print only the desired information from the Zap log

Tags: go, logging, go-zap

I would like to know if there is a method to print only the desired information from a Zap log, with the following fields:

`{"level":50,"time":"2023-07-03T13:55:31.351Z","pid":false,"prefix":"auth","trace_id":"16e853160c98d7c40ab78c2111c46a2f","span_id":"65f94b2ff825492b","error_message":"str.toLowerCase1 is not a function","function_name":"signin","controller_name":"LoginController"}`

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to extract and display only the relevant details from this log entry. Any guidance on achieving this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!